# Can anyone explain why a Flask Electroscope does not work without the flask?

Tags: electrostatics

I'm a HS Physics teacher and I'm trying to guide students through explorations of electrostatics.

One of the tools we have is a "flask electroscope". It is an Erlenmeyer Flask with a rubber stopper. Through the stopper is a vertical metal rod. On top of the rod is a metal sphere. On the bottom of the rod, there are two leaves of foil that hang freely next to each other. When you bring a charged object (positive or negative) close to the metal sphere, the leaves repel one another due to charge separation. This I understand.

Here's my conundrum and question. I was trying to demonstrate that the leaves repel from each other rather than from the charged object, so I pulled the stopper/rod/sphere/leaves contraption out of the flask and held onto the stopper with my hand. But in this configuration, when a charged object is brought to the sphere - even a highly charged balloon - the leaves do not repel each other at all.

Who can explain the above phenomenon??? What is the purpose of the flask in making the electroscope work? None of the explanations of it's operation mention anything about the flask. I always assumed it was simply to prevent drafts of air.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @EdV +1. Good hypothesis. Glass is a much better insulator than black (carbon-filled) rubber.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion has been made that the rubber bung becomes leaky.
To test that hypothesis reconstruct the electroscope with the bung loosing fitting into the flask.
Charge the electroscope, eg by induction, and the leaves repel.
Now carefully remove the bung using your fingers and making sure only the outside of the bung is touched.
Is there a deflection or not?

If there is no deflection you have now to carefully replace the bung into the flask.
Is there a deflection or not?
The reason for doing this is to check whether or not your proximity to the leaves affects how much they deflect, ie there might still be charge on the electroscope but your proximity affects where it resides.

Trying drying the bung with a fan heater to see if a surface layer of moisture compromises the bulk insulating properties of the rubber.

Another thing to try is to check the insulating properties of the bung by reconstruction the electroscope and charging it.
Now touch the bung with an earthed wire keep your hand a distance from the bung.
Is there any change in the deflection?

With the reconstructed electroscope does the deflection change if the flask is held in a hand?

---

The flask is there as a support for the bung and to reduce air currents which might make the foil move.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility exists.  It's probable that electrons are continuously "leaking off" of the foil leaves of the electroscope, into the surrounding air.  Since the flask is an insulator that contains a small amount of trapped air, there is a limit to how much charge can leak off when the cork is tightly inserted into the flask, but there is no limit to the charge leakage when the leaves of the electroscope are exposed to room air.

While this is just a hypothesis, it is definitely known that there is leakage from Van de Graaff generators into ambient air.  On humid days, this leakage is so high that it is difficult to get a decent spark out of these devices.

Answer (score 0):

Others noted that the stopper may have some conductivity. Another possibility is a discharge between the rod and your hand.